# How can i delete child in Many to One relational in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Firstly, I have tables like below:

```
 class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__= "parent"

    id = db.Column("parent_id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    childFirst = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('childFirst.childFirst_id'))
    childSecond = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('childSecond.childSecond_id'))
    childThird = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('childThird. childThird_id'))

    child_first = db.relationship("ChildFirst")
    child_second = db.relationship("ChildSecond")
    child_third = db.relationship("ChildThird")

 class ChildFirst(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "childFirst"

    id = db.Column("childFirst_id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

 class ChildSecond(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "childSecond"

    id = db.Column("childSecond_id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

 class ChildThird(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "childThird"

    id = db.Column("childThird_id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

So, I build many to one relation as documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one)

But when I try to delete one of Childs I am getting an error
Error:

```
'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`<DB_NAME>`.`<PARENT_NAME>`, CONSTRAINT `<PARENT_NAME>_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`<CHILD_ID_COLUMN>`) REFERENCES `<CHILD_TABLE_NAME>` (`<CHILD_ID_COLUMN>`))')
[SQL: DELETE FROM CHILD_TABLE_NAME WHERE <CHILD_TABLE_NAME>.<CHILD_ID_COLUMN> = %(<CHILD_ID_COLUMN>_1)s]
```

And actually I am trying to delete child with this command -> `CHILD_CLASS.query.filter_by(id=<id_variable>).delete()`

Lastly, I am using mysql database.

So, What is wrong ?

Thanks and best regards..

Answer (score 0):

When I delete child row, I deleted successfully.

Code:

```
child = <CHILD_CLASS>.query.filter_by(id=<id>).first()
db.session.delete(child)
db.session.commit()
```

But what is the difference ?

Comment: I believe this is a part of your question. Consider modifying your question to instead of adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot delete or update a parent row` makes it all clear. Even though you are using the terms Child and Parent here, the actual child in your case is the `Parent` and the parent is actually `Child`. To understand this, simply notice that the `Parent` table holds the reference id of 'its' parent, which is the `Child table`.

Simply put, the database cannot allow you to delete a member of Child class because a member of the Parent class has a reference to it - this is referential integrity.

To succeed in this operation, you need to tell the database how it should handle cases when the parent is deleted - i.e. by a cascade. For cascade options, have a look at [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html).